# Compilation failure with maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I'm trying to build a spark application with maven in eclipse but I got a compilation failure. I fixed `JAVA_HOME` system variable giving it the path to my JDK and not to the JRE as follows:

```
Name:JAVA_HOME , value:C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73
```

and I added this string to `PATH` variable `"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\bin"`, but it didn't work. 
So, I tried without `"\bin"` as follows `"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73"` but nothing new.

So I, tried to point my JDK through eclipse as follows: `window->preferences->java->installed JREs`, and I have chosen the JDK too but this solution didn't work either, so I decided to fix it using cmd :

```
set JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73"

echo %JAVA_HOME%

set PATH=%PATH%;%JAVA_HOME%\bin

echo %PATH%
```

and I checked `java -version` and the result was `jdk1.8.0_73` so I thought that all was alright but it wasn't.

Sometimes I have in the error message that `tools.jar` is missing and sometimes I get other error that mentions that maybe I'm using a JRE not a JDK (but I'm sure that I'm pointing the JDK). It appears on [image: this image].

the image 2 shows my `pom.xml` file:

this is the first error when i use the `maven-compile-plugin` in my file pom.xml as shown in the image

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project myapp: Compilation failure [ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?

but when i replace it by `maven-resources-plugin`, than I get this error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) on project myapp: Fatal error compiling: tools.jar not found: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_91..\lib\tools.jar -> [Help 1] [ERROR] [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch. [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

I tried the command `mvn -v` and I found the maven home (D:\apache-maven-3.1.1) so it is normal but the surprise was for java home (C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\jre). I checked again the variable Path but it is correct (C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\bin) what is the problem?

help please I wasted much time trying to fix this issue.

I selected my project->build path->configure build path->libraries->jre system library->edit->execution environment-> select javaSE-1.8 (jdk 1.8.0-73), normally this means that i'm using java1.8 but I got these log of errors:

> [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ myapp --
>   [WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
>
> [INFO] Copying 0 resource
>   [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ myapp ---
>
> [WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding Cp1252, i.e. build is platform dependent!
>
> [INFO] Compiling 1 source file to C:\Users\pc\Desktop\eclipse\myapp\target\classes
>   [ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
>
> [ERROR] C:\Users\pc\Desktop\eclipse\myapp\src\main\java\myapp\Main.java:[107,38] error: lambda expressions are not supported in -source 1.5
>   [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
>
> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) on project myapp: Compilation failure
>
> [ERROR] C:\Users\pc\Desktop\eclipse\myapp\src\main\java\myapp\Main.java:[107,38] error: lambda expressions are not supported in -source 1.5

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: The first thing we should have seen here was the exact error messages you're getting, and please don't use screenshots, just provide the exact text of the error messages.

Comment: maybe there is somthing missing in the pom file, can any one take a look?

Answer (score 1):

When you change your JAVA_HOME variable does not mean you are changing your Eclipse configuration. Eclipse manage his own variables and you can set as many JDKs as you want. You need to add and assign your JDK to your project in eclipse.

Right click on your project, Build Path->Configure Build Path. Select "JRE System Library" in the right options select edit and then configure your JDK.

Comment: what i have to choose? execution environment or alternate JRE? if i choose the first one than there are many options (CDC/foundation-J2SE-JRE-JAVASE-OSGI/minimum) so which one i have to select?

Comment: i selected javaSE1.8(jdk 1.8.0_73) but still not working

Answer (score 0):

my problem was unexpected because finally the problem was in the pom.xml file not in settings, i corrected only this plugin in the pom file and all is fine.

```
           <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
             <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```